# Python saving empty plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

> EDIT: This question is a duplicate. Original question's link is posted above.

I am using Python to plot a set of values which are showing good on the Python terminal (using Jupyter NoteBook) but when I save it, the saved file when opened shows an empty (completely white) photo. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,3,4])
plt.show()
plt.savefig('E:/1.png')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should save the plot before closing it: indeed, `plt.show()` dislays the plot, and blocks the execution until after you close it; hence when you attempt to save on the next instruction, the plot has been destroyed and can no longer be saved.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,3,4])
plt.savefig('E:/1.png')   # <-- save first
plt.show()                # <-- then display
```

Comment: If you are working in jupyter notebook and don't use inline plots, then you should save the figure in the same cell. If you execute `savefig` in the next cell the execution is blocked.

Comment: This is correct @LisaB.

Answer (score 4):

When you execute the show, `plt` clears the graph. Just invert the execution of `show` and `savefig`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,3,4])
plt.savefig('E:/1.png')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `plt.show()` command is "using up" the plot object when you call it. Putting the `plt.savefig()` command before it should allow it to work.

Also, if you're using Jupyter notebooks you don't even need to use `plt.show()`, you just need `%matplotlib` inline somewhere in your notebook to have plots automatically get displayed.