# savefig returns a blank image

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, savefig

I am trying to plot a pandas dataframe (result_m) using the pandas plotting function, but when I try to save the figure using savefig but it returns a blank pdf.  It plots fine in the notebook window.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong

```
fig = plt.figure()

ax = result_m.plot( kind='line',  figsize=(20, 10),fontsize=15)
ax.set_title('Harkins Slough Diversions',fontsize= 20) 
ax.set_xlabel( "Date",fontsize=18)
ax.set_ylabel("cubic meters",fontsize=18)
plt.legend(fontsize=15)

fig.savefig(os.path.join(outPath4,'plot_fig.pdf'))
```

Comment: Please take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51203839/python-saving-empty-plot/51203929, and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib (pyplot) savefig outputs blank image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012487/matplotlib-pyplot-savefig-outputs-blank-image)

Comment: @AkibRhast I think this is a slightly different question, since this involves pandas plots not being added to a matplotlib figure by default, whereas those posts mostly deal with matplotlib directly, and how plt.show clears the figure.

Comment: I see, I see I google fig.savefig() and it brought up matplotlib.. so i figured that is what he is using? @MichaelDelgado
So is his savefig pandas?

Comment: The OP is using matplotlib.pyplot.Figure.savefig, which is a matplotlib method, but the plot they are trying to save is being  generated using pandas.DataFrame.plot.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the plot you create is not on the figure you create (and save). In the second line:

```py
ax = result_m.plot( kind='line',  figsize=(20, 10),fontsize=15)
```

pandas creates a new figure, since you did not supply an axis (`ax`) argument. See the pandas docs on [plotting to specific subplots](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/visualization.html#targeting-different-subplots).

You could fix this by either skipping the figure creation step, then getting the figure pandas creates from the axis object:

```py
ax = result_m.plot( kind='line',  figsize=(20, 10),fontsize=15)
fig = ax.figure
```

or by adding the plot to the figure you created, by first creating a subplot:

```py
fig = plt.figure(size=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax = result_m.plot( kind='line',  fontsize=15, ax=ax)
```

Note that in this option, define the figure's `size` attribute when you create the figure, rather than by passing `figsize` to `DataFrame.plot`.